# Cloudkit - Dashboard - There are no "Entity" records in this database

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dashboard, cloudkit

I'm trying to store some data in Cloudkit by Xcode but when I push QueryRecords in the Dashboard "There are no "Entity" records in this database" is displayed but my "SaveFunction" reports a "Saved successfully". Did I miss something ? I'm very stuck.... Thank you for any help you can offer!...

**1) Signing & Capabilities Part** :

- Key-value storage checked
- CloudKit checked
- Containers iCloud.com.myusername.nameOfTheProject

**2) Xcdatamodeld**

- "Entity" contains 5 attributes, the first entity has a Default Value

**3) AppDelegate Part**

- import UIKit
- import CoreData

[...]

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "NameOfContainer")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })

    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

**4) ViewController**

- import UIKit
- import CloudKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let myContainer = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.MyUserName.NameOfTheProject")

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let artworkRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Entity")

    artworkRecord["customFieldName"] = "xxxx" as NSString


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let privateDatabase = myContainer.privateCloudDatabase

    privateDatabase.save(artworkRecord) { (record, error) in
        if let error = error {
                print(error)
            // Insert error handling
            return
        }
        print("Saved successfully")
        // Insert successfully saved record code
    }   
}
```

}

**5) CloudKit Dashboard**

- The Container selected is the good one
- Database : Private Database with my same Id used in Xcode
- Zone : _DefaultZone
- Custom field "customFieldName" displayed ("queryable, searchable,
  sortable") as xcdatamodeld
- "recordName" field created with an Index Type QUERYABLE

Comment: I'd start by trying to do something with the record that is coming back inside the completion handler for the save function just to make sure it is what you expected.  Alternatively, I'd also consider a test of storing it in the public db to make sure you are looking at the right private db.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, storing records in the Public Database seems working but not for the private.

Answer (score 3):

Please, check if your development account and your iCloud account on your test device are the same. I also have the problem, when I test iCloud access on a test device, that has a different apple-id then my development apple-id.

Like the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/enabling_cloudkit_in_your_app) in the section "Select or Create an iCloud Account for Development" says: "Note that your iCloud account is distinct from your Apple Developer account; however, you can use the same email address for both. Doing so gives you access to your iCloud account’s private user data in CloudKit Dashboard, which can be helpful for debugging."

You are using the private database and if you then want to see the private records, your test device must have the same apple-id as your development account id.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Turns out CoreData doesn't use the zone `_defaultZone` for private databases. Instead, it created one called `com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone`.

After switching the filter to the correct zone I can query all records created using my own user.

[image]

I couldn't find any documentation about this, but will update the answer if I discover more about it.

Comment: If you cannot find the com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone in the selection dropdown, navigate to "Zones" in the left sidebar and let it fetch the zones. After that it appeared for me.